# sum of squares two primes does not equal square of another prime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

If for example you have three primes, x, y, z. And both x and y are smaller than z.
How do I prove that for any primes x,y,z:  $x^2 + y^2 \neq z^2$

would this be done by stating that the squares of an odd (since they're prime) number will always be odd, thus you would end up with the sum of two odd numbers, which ends up being even. and that contradicts the above statement?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: $$x^2=z^2-y^2=(z-y)(z+y)$$ how about playing with this?

Comment: Alternative approach: from [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), if $x,y,z$ are all primes, then they must form a primitive Pythagorean triplet, which requires that one of $x,y$ be even.  This means that (without loss of generality), $y$ must equal $(2)$.  This would require that $x,z$ are two odd prime numbers such that $z^2 - x^2 = 4.$  That can't happen, because the minimum value for $(z-x)$ will be $(2)$, and the minimum value for $(z+x)$ is $(5 + 3) = 8 > 2.$